# How do I convert this pseudocode Enhanced InsertionSort to C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, arraylist, pseudocode

I am a student and have been given the pseudocode for an Enhanced InsertionSort, but I am really struggling to convert it to C#.

The pseudocode:

> 1. Calculate length n
> 2. var i=1,j
> 3. if (a[i] < a [i-1]), then
> 4. if (a[i] < a [0]), then
> 5. set j = 0 and goto-35
> 6. else j = i/2 and goto-10
> 7. end if
> 8. else i++ and repeat-3
> 9. end if
> 10. if (a[i]
>
>     elseif (if (a[i] = = a[j]), then
>
>     set j = j+1 and goto-35
>
>     end if
>
>     else goto-25
>
>     end if
>
>     while((j-1)>=0), do
>
>     j = j-2 and if (a[i]>a[j]), then
>
>     if (a[i] < a [j+1]), then
>
>     set j = j+1 and goto-35
>
>     else set j = j+2 and goto-35
>
>     end if
>
>     else if (a[i] = =a[j]), then
>
>     Set j = j+1 and goto-35
>
>     Else return
>
>     While (((i-1)-j) > = 0 ), do
>
>     J = j+2 and (a[i] < a[j]), then
>
>     If (a[i] < a [j-1]), then
>
>     Set j=j-1 and goto-35
>
>     Else set j+j+0 and goto-35
>
>     End if
>
>     Else if (a[i]= = a[j]), then
>
>     Set j=j+1 and goto-35
>
>     Else return
>
>     End if
>
>     Swap a[i] and a[j]
>
>     j++
>
>     while(j=i-1), do
>
>     i++ and goto-3
>
>     END

So far, what I have written in C# is this:

```
static public void EnhancedInsertionSort(ArrayList List)
{
    int n = List.Count;
    int i = 1;
    int j = i-1;

    do
    {
        if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() < ((Webpage)List[i - 1]).getVisits())
        {
            if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() < ((Webpage)List[0]).getVisits())
            {
                j = 0;
                object temp = List[i];
                List[i] = List[j];
                List[j] = temp;
                j++;
            }
            else
                j = i / 2;
        }
        else
            i++;
        if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() < ((Webpage)List[j]).getVisits())
        {
            while ((j - 1) >= 0)
            {
                j = j - 2;
                if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() > ((Webpage)List[j]).getVisits())
                {
                    if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() < ((Webpage)List[j + 1]).getVisits())
                    {
                        j = j + 1;
                        object temp = List[i];
                        List[i] = List[j];
                        List[j] = temp;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() == ((Webpage)List[j]).getVisits())
                        j = j + 1;
                    else return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            if (((Webpage)List[i]).getVisits() == ((Webpage)List[j]).getVisits())
            j = j + 1;

    } while (j == i-1);

}
```

But now I am completely confused and stuck. I am sure I have made some interpretation mistakes, as I am struggling with the "goto" keywords and how to convert them to C# loops. I have researched this, and understand the basic idea, but with so many `goto` keywords used in one algorithm I am finding the process very confusing.

I would really appreciate any help that anyone can offer!

Note: I am trying to sort an ArrayList of objects ("Webpage") in descending order on the attribute Visits (integer value).

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code is an old invention, and being pseudo code has not been updated to modern languages. I believe the old GOTO sentence should be replaces with calls to subroutines (or functions) to execute the little functions. In example:

```
static public void EnhancedInsertionSort(ArrayList List)
{
    int n = List.Count;
    int i = 1;
    int j = i-1;

    do
    {
        if ( pageWithLessVisits(List[i], List[i - 1]) )
        {
            if ( pageWithLessVisits(List[i], List[0]) )
            {
                j = 0;
                object temp = List[i];
                List[i] = List[j];
                List[j] = temp;
                j++;
            }
            else
                j = i / 2;
        }
        else
            i++;
        if (pageWithLessVisits(List[i],List[j]))
        {
            while ((j - 1) >= 0)
            {
                j = j - 2;
                if (pageWithMoreVisits(List[i], List[j]))
                {
                    if (pageWithLessVisits(List[i],List[j + 1]))
                    {
                        j = j + 1;
                        object temp = List[i];
                        List[i] = List[j];
                        List[j] = temp;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (pageWithEqualVisits(List[i], List[j]))
                        j = j + 1;
                    else return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            if (pageWithEqualVisits(List[i], List[j]))
                j = j + 1;

    } while (j == i-1);

}

static private bool pageWithLessVisits(Webpage page1, Webpage page2)
{
    return page1.getVisits() < page2.getVisits()
}

static private bool pageWithMoreVisits(Webpage page1, Webpage page2)
{
    return page1.getVisits() > page2.getVisits()
}

static private bool pageWithEqualVisits(Webpage page1, Webpage page2)
{
    return page1.getVisits() == page2.getVisits()
}
```

You can even encapsulate the little code inside de IFs. Making the code as legible as the pseudo code.